# What scriptures describe Durvasa having three sons who promulgated Agamas?

Tags: shaivism, agamas, tantra, kashmiri-shaivism

Generally, Vaishnavas follow the Pancharatra Agamas, Shaivites follow the Shaiva Agamas, and Shaktas follow the Shaiva Agamas. But long ago, there was a group of people in Kashmir who followed the Shakta Agamas but adopted Shiva as their Ishta Devata. That group evolved into what we now call Kashmir Shaivism. Because it has its roots in Shakta Agamas, it subscribes to a monistic philosophy, as opposed to philosophic Shaivite sects like Shaiva Siddhanta which are more dualistic in their philosophy.

Now the most famous Kashmiri Shaivite philosopher was Abhinavagupta, who lived in the 10th century.  Abhinavagupta's guru was Lakshmanagupta, whose guru was Utpaladeva, whose guru was Somananda.  Now Somananda was the shishya of Vasugupta, the author of the Shiva Sutras, the defining text of Kashmiri Shaivism.  But that's not the only lineage Somananda is associated with.  Somananda is also claimed to be a biological descendant of Durvasa's son Tryamabaka, who is also revered as a Kashmiri Shaivite Acharya.  Here is what Abhinavagupta says about Tryambaka in [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/JQAw) from his Tantraloka:

> As, thus, with the disappearance of the Shāstras the world became engrossed in spiritual darkness, Shiva-as the Deity is called-took pity on men and, appearing on the Kailāsa mountain in the form of Shrikantha, commanded the Sage Durvasas to spread in the world the knowledge of these Shāstras again. **Durvasas, thus commanded, created, by the power of his mind, three sons - Tryambaka, Amardaka and Shrinātha** by names - whom he charged with the mission of establishing spiritual order and of teaching men again the ancient and eternal Shaiva faith and doctrine in their three aspects of Abheda, Bheda and Bhedabheda-of Unity, Diversity and Diversity-in-unity. Tryambaka was to teach the first, Amardaka the second, while Shrinatha was to have the charge of the last, It is this Abheda or Advaya Shaiva teaching, thus retaught to the world by Tryambaka, which is spoken of as the Trika.

Trika is basically what we now call the Kashmiri Shaivism.  In any case, the idea is that Tryambaka promulgated the 64 Bhairava Tantras which Kashmiri Shaivites focus on, whereas Amardaka and Srinatha promulgated the 28 traditional Shaiva Agamas which philosophical Shaivite sects like Shaiva Siddhanta are based on.

But my question is, what scriptures describe Durvasa's mind-born sons Tryambaka, Amardaka, and Srinatha?  Do any Puranas or Agamas mention them?

The only putative sons of Durvasa I know of are Ilvala and Vatapi who were killed by the sage Agastya.  Ilvala and Vatapi are mentioned in Hindu scripture, but their being sons of Durvasa may just be folklore.

Comment: Oh. Are you 100% sure he was the same Durvasā rishi?

Comment: @RohitSinghRathore Yeah, it is the same Durvasa.  I've seen other books that explicitly call him the son of Atri while telling this story.

Comment: then better invoice those sayings here. Will help everyone. :)

Comment: @RohitSinghRathore Here's one such book: https://books.google.com/books?id=ZM-BlvaqAf0C&lpg=PA14&dq=tryambaka%20amardaka&pg=PA14#v=onepage&q=tryambaka%20amardaka&f=false It gives the story of Tryambaka, Amardaka, and Srinatha in the context of describing Dattatreya's brother Durvasa.

Comment: Now I think Durvasa can be a post also.

Comment: And your 1st para is contradicting your own writing both in the quote & other questions. It was propagated by Durvasa then how can you say ShAkta agamas followers established KS?

Comment: @Rohit. Well, I think Durvasa, along with Dattatreya and Chandra, were born multiple times.  In any case, I'm not aware of scriptures mentioning any Durvasa having three sons with these names, let alone the present Durvasa.

Comment: hmmm... SomAnanda, Vasugupta, UtpAldeva, Lakshmangupta, Abhinavgupta, Kshemraj etc never had such question.

Comment: @Rohit. Well, I'm not convinced that this story of Durvasa's sons is true. Kashmiri Shaivites group the 28 Shaiva Agamas together with the 64 Bhairava Tantras, but others would dispute that characterization. The Shaiva Siddhanta sect, for instance, rejects the 64 Bhairava Tantras.  The Bhairava Tantras are fundamentally Shakta Agamas rather than Shaiva Agamas, even if they happen to venerate the Bhairava form of Shiva.

Comment: @Rohit. Yeah, I don't find it surprising that those Kashmiri Shaivite philosophers believe in this grouping of Shaiva Agamas and Bhairava Tantras.

Comment: Yes, I too think you are more intelligent, knowledgeable & realized than Abhinavgupta who couldn't think like you. :)

Comment: Haha, you don't need to rely on my intelligence, you can really on the intelligence of Shaiva Siddhanta Acharyas like Meykandar, Appayya Dikshitar, Arulnandi Shivacharya, Shivagra Yogi, etc.

Comment: Sure, will read them whoever seem to be self realized but I am not interested in reading parrots who by themselves experienced naught. Would like to even read  non Orthodox like Jiddu Krishnamurthi who talks what they experience.

Comment: @Rohit. Well, a lot of them claim to have experienced something.  Like Appayya Dikshitar would get drunk and then have mystical visions.

Comment: Saying honestly, I am satisfied with Shaiva absolutism. Although due to Islamic invasion the system has lost its many scriptures but still I find KS fascinating because I find the ways in KS to experience divinity by myself while alive rather than **relying/supposing to get some permanent destination after death.**

Comment: Moreover, if you haven't found yet, all mine above comments were sarcastic which were taking KS āchāryas lightly. Some secrets are known in traditions only, if Āchārya Abhinavgupta said in his Tantraloka, it has elements of truth in it (at least I  trust). It doesn't make any iota of differences whether **you're convinced or not** to me. :P