# Kailāshpati Mahādeva is not the destroyer (one among Trinity)?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, agamas, tantra, kashmiri-shaivism

There are many planes of existence, grouped into hierarchies. Everything which is inside of human being is fated to be manifested outside ( or vice versa) is the reason of existence of worlds. Therefore, respective tattvas are the material cause of the existence of worlds as shown in the pic. 
 
From the pic, Lord Rudra has been named among Trinity for the *Sakala beings*. Also, as it can be seen,  **Sri Kantha Nath** is the Lord of the upper plane of **pralayākalas beings.** 
As it has been explained in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18278/8696) question how Kanthanāth started lineage of Shaiva agamas, in fact Kanthanāth is the source of almost all 'Shiva-Shakti' agamas. But a verse of Matanga āgama drew my attention as it seems **Sri Kanthanāth is Mahadeva only.**.

> Having deeply involved himself primarily in the worship of Siva, Sage Matanga played the flute with intense and deep devotion for a long time, his inner self all the time being  engrossed in delighted and blissful state. Thereupon, the **Supreme Lord Srikantha, along with His consort Parvati**, manifested before Matanga, who was the most celebrated one and who had accomplished great penance and enabled him to see His own form directly.

Also, we find same in Mrigendra āgama

> **Lord Umapati** who set the tree of Manmatha to be engulfed by the flames of fire emitted from His forehead eye received this Agama from **Anantesvara**. He, in turn, revealed this Agama to me in an abridged way, reducing the number of the verses to 11,000. Avoiding the elaboration as much as possible, I now proceed to instruct the principles set forth in this Agama which are free from inconsistency and ambiguity. I reveal  to you the important principles largely through the  same statements as employed in this Agama.” 1.27.

Note that Lord Ananteshvar is that Lord Shiva which is efficient cause of the world. Btw, from the pic we also find the planes of pralayākalas are result of *Purusha & Prakriti tattvas*. Lord Mahadeva & Goddess Uma are called *Purusha & Prakriti* respectively as well which is in consistence. **These facts conclude Lord Mahadeva is not among Trinity but he is Lord of higher plane.** In any case he too can be called Rudra but not the Lord Rudra as the destroyer among Trinity supergods.

So, my question is, are there any scriptures other than āgamas which talk about **Lord Mahadeva not being destroyer (i.e, not one among Trinity) but the supreme reality of higher plane** *either indirectly or indirectly*?

[image: Cosmology]

Comment: The [Atharvasikha](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atharvashikha_Upanishad) talks of Shiva who is beyond Brahma, Vishnu and Rudra. And it doesn't magically declare it. It takes text from Gopatha Brahmana of Atharvaveda. Regarding indirect refrences there are many refrences like you can check 15th chapter of Atharvaveda, 5th Anuvaka of Rudram, Svetasvatara Upanishad etc... and obviously Mahabharata and Puranas certainly state...

Comment: As per Shiva Purana, Kailashapathi Shankara is destroyer among trimurties though Kailasapati Shankara represents Supreme Brahman.

Comment: Interesting...!

Comment: What? @TheDestroyer Lord Shankar is different from Lord Mahadeva?

Comment: @RohitSinghRathore What does Shiva Agamas say about "Mahadeva"? Do they say Mahadeva stays on Kailasa Parvata?

Comment: @TheDestroyer I have yet to find. But read 11th chapter of Mrigendra āgama.

Comment: @RohitSinghRathore I think we will know that if we know relationship between Mahadeva and Shankara or Rudra. I guess three are synonymous.

Comment: Yes @TheDestroyer I'm also thinking which one is Lord Rudra the destroyer then? I think he appears during dissolution only.

Comment: @Rohit Singh Rathore Yeah you may be right because in Mahabharata Krishna says to Shiva "युगान्ते चैव सम्प्राप्ते रुद्रमङ्गात्सृजत्प्रभुः" / "who takes the form of Rudra in the end of Yugas."

Comment: @Tezz 11th chapter of Mrigendra āgama describes many Lord Rudras. :O

Comment: Tree Dev are Brahma (Creator), VIshnu (Protector) and Shiv (Destroyer). Aren't the Shankar, Mahadev, Rudra are different form or name of same person (Shiv), exactly same as Devi Parvati has 9 different forms like Durga, Kali etc.?